# Listing all Openmeta Tags and associated Files

Tags: software-recommendation, macos

Some month ago I started using [openmeta](http://code.google.com/p/openmeta/) tags to manage my files. Is there a tool which shows all openmeta tags on my mac and the files tagged with these tags?

Comment: https://github.com/jdberry/tag/issues/17 is 'Add limited support for OpenMeta'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

### [Tags](http://www.caseapps.com/tags/)

By **[CASEapps](http://www.caseapps.com/)**.

- Lists all created tags and files associated with them
- Can tag
- Easy search filtration
- QuickLook

[image: Tags]

---

### [Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/index.html)

By **[Ironic.](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/)**

- Lists all created tags and files associated with them
- Can tag
- Easy search filtration
- Ratings
- Heavier/more feature rich interface

[image: leap]

---

### [TagLists](http://hasseg.org/tagLists/)

By **[Ali Rantakari](http://hasseg.org/)**

- **Free**
- Tags & Tag searches for file lists must be made manually

  - ie. doesn't list created tags, which was what you were after

    - but hey, the price is right!

[image: taglists]

Comment: A down vote from be because (unless I'm missing something), Leap does not reliably find files that have OpenMeta tags alone. That surprises me.

Comment: Additional context: this answer is amongst the examples that are offered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261875/166799 under *How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?*.

Answer (score 0):

### Listing all tags

I'm not presently aware of a "blessed" way to list all tags on the system; [Jari's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24514/516451) is probably the best solution for this component of the question.

### Finding files with a tag

The "blessed" way to search for files with a specific tag is by using Apple's [`mdfind`](https://ss64.com/mac/mdfind.html) tool in the Terminal.

For example, here's how to use it to find all files in all directories with the `work` user tag:

```sh
mdfind "kMDItemOMUserTags == 'work'"
```

To limit it to a specific directory, use the `-onlyin` parameter:

```sh
mdfind "kMDItemOMUserTags == 'work'" -onlyin ./
```

For more flags, see [`man mdfind`](https://ss64.com/mac/mdfind.html).

Answer (score -2):

Nifty Box was a great free, scriptable application.

I wrote some nice AppleScripts that could go through tags and color certain files.

---

Links (added by grahamperrin): http://web.archive.org/web/20120623015606/http://www.nifty-box.com/ … [discontinued on or before 2012-06-23](http://web.archive.org/web/20120905135820/http://www.nifty-box.com/).

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the program, and perhaps a link?