# Can I use the Terminal to find all OpenMeta tags on my system?

Tags: terminal, script

I know that there are [apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24494/listing-all-openmeta-tags-and-associated-files) that can do this, so I figure it must be possible: I'd like to compile a list of every OpenMeta tag that I've used on my Mac (OS X 10.8.3). But here's the rub: I'd ideally like it to be scriptable, so that I can manipulate the list after creating it. The only thing that's come to mind so far is doing an `mdfind "kMDItemOMUserTags == *"` and then running `xattr` on every single result, but that seems wildly inefficient and silly. So does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: mdfind and xattr seem to be quite acceptable solutions.

Comment: In Stack Overflow: [How can I add OS X “tags” to files programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19720376/38108) (2013-11-01)