# List all tags in Terminal in Mavericks?

Tags: terminal, macos, finder-tag

Is it feasible to list all tags already defined in OS X in Terminal?

I know there are some third-party applications that list all tags, but I just want to use Terminal to find all tags, since I use [this tool](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) to work with tags in Terminal (but unfortunately the tool doesn't provide to list tags for an entire system - it just lists for a single or multiple files selected arbitrarily).

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: [Listing all Openmeta Tags and associated Files](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24494/8546) (2011-09-08)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tags name are in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.list`.

You can read it with

```
defaults read com.apple.finder.plist ViewSettingsDictionary
```

It will need some parsing to be a bit clearer :

```
defaults read com.apple.finder.plist ViewSettingsDictionary | 
    awk 'NR%12==2'| grep -o '".*"' |  sed 's/^.\(.*\).\{18\}$/\1/'
```

Other possibility is parsing the plist as xml. To do that you'll need to first convert the plist from binary to xml using.

`plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Comment: Hmmm... even if I used `awk` the result was clumsy, as I got something like ` "mytag_Tag_ViewSettings" =     {`, where `mytag` is what I'm looking for. Thus I think it's much easier to just open Finder and navigate toward the tag bar. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I updated my parsing part, it now returns only the name :)

Comment: Everybody should look at @TedWise answer below, it explains why the list obtained through this method is not complete.

Comment: FYI: With OS X El Capitan, the equivalent command is, `defaults read com.apple.finder.plist FavoriteTagNames`.  However, that list doesn't include custom tag names.

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer. It just doesn't work at all. It doesn't show my custom tags.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag):

```
tag -tgf \*|grep '^    '|cut -c5-|sort -u
```

`tag -f \*` finds all files with tags, `-t` includes tag names in the output, and `-g` prints each tag on a separate line.

Comment: No mention of OpenMeta in the opening question, but it's worth noting that the current version of `tag` does not list OpenMeta tags on Mavericks. https://github.com/jdberry/tag/issues/17 is 'Add limited support for OpenMeta'.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, only this creates a complete tag list here.

Answer (score 4):

That list isn't comprehensive. It's only tags added through Finder. There's an additional file `~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist`, that also lists the tags that have been manipulated in Finder.

If you tagged a file in Terminal or using another tool and never manipulated the tags in Finder, then the tags won't be in either list.

Comment: I tagged a file with the `Tag` app that others mentioned. The tag then appears in the Finder > Preferences > Tags list, so it must be stored somewhere, though. Do we know where it's stored?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use mdfind in combination with mdls to get the same result:

```
/usr/bin/mdfind -0 "(kMDItemUserTags == '*')" |xargs -0 mdls -name kMDItemUserTags |grep '^    ' |cut -c5- |cut -d , -f 1 |sort -u
```

Would be interesting to benchmark, which one is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Colour followed by path:

`/usr/bin/mdfind -0 "(kMDItemUserTags == '*')" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo $(mdls -name kMDItemUserTags % | grep "^    " |cut -c5-) %'`

Comment: I get error `xargs: unterminated quote`